# Script for compression multiple files based on name

Tags: powershell, compression

I need your help with one script,

Got 560 files, there is 280 files with extension .xml and 280 files with extension .vid - name in each pair is same, just extension is different,

I need query in powershell which could join 2 files, abc1.xml + abc1.vid  into one abc1.zep file

Right now got something like that:

```
$compress = @{
  Path = "C:\Users\user.account\Desktop\New folder\01102022004707008-LW2888-000064650-57415253.xml", "C:\Users\user.account\Desktop\New folder\01102022004707008-LW2888-000064650-57415253.vid"
  CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
  DestinationPath = "C:\Users\user.account\Desktop\New folder\01102022004707008-LW2888-000064650-57415253.zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress
```

But i would have to edit name 280 times ;P can get names for all files, its not an issue but i need something automatic, something which could avoid manual correction :D

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group your files by shared base name, then process each group.

```bash
Get-ChildItem *.xml, *.vid |
  Group-Object BaseName |
  ForEach-Object {
    $compress = @{
      LiteralPath = $_.Group.FullName
      CompressionLevel = 'Fastest'
      DestinationPath = Join-Path (Split-Path $_.Group[0].FullName) "$($_.Name).zip"
    }
    Compress-Archive @compress
  }
```

- `$_.Group` is a collection of the objects that make up the group at hand, i.e. the [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem); accessing `.FullName` using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) returns an array of the file's full paths.
- `$_.Name` contains the value of the grouping criterion, i.e. the shared base name (`.BaseName` property value).

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BravoS